# Perform an action when a program starts

Tags: windows, winapi, hook, vcl

Let's say I wanted to run a batch file when a specific EXE is started. Are there any hooks for this in the Win32 API?

I'm using VCL with Delphi, but general info on this would be nice as well.
The program is supposed to run in the background, and, when the user starts an application, the program detects this, checks whether the application matches the criteria and runs the associated batch file if so.

Comment: As far as I can find from a quick web search, you can't receive notifications from programs that are started. You can perform polling, but chances are you're too late then. If you explained the problem itself better, a more foolproof solution might be suggested. Can you, for example, create a custom executable or batch file that the user starts, so the code you want to run runs on beforehand, and after that the application the user desires to start is started?

Comment: @CodeCaster Yes, that would indeed work.

Comment: You can take a look at the [AppInit_DLLs](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/197571) registry value to load a DLL when the process loads.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use the Create Process Function of Delphi?

Here is a small link that it can guide you for the process:

http://snipplr.com/view/59064/using-createprocess-to-execute-programs/

Comment: What I need is something that basically detects when a process is started. I've updated the question with additional info, which will hopefully clear up any confusion.
`The program is supposed to run in the background, and, when the user starts an application, the program detects this, checks whether the application matches the criteria and runs the associated batch file if so.`

Comment: ok, so like a TSR program, I still belive that with a thead that create a process can be handle it. If I get any other solution I will post it.